# Tracking conversions accurately in Drupal

Tags: google-analytics, drupal, event-tracking

Just wondering can a conversion (page view) on a URL that looks like the following:

/node/17/done?sid=1803&token=aadf592c136d5b94088e792c788d1d24

be counted as multiple conversions in google analytics?

Tried to load the page in web archive